# how to compile c++ program in mac terminal

Tags: c++, macos

i wrote a program in my mac using sublime text as the plateform..

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
        {
        cout<<"HELLOW WORLD";
        return 0;
        }
```

this was my program.. 
i saved it in desktop as hellow.cpp

while compiling on mac terminal as g++ hellow.cpp, i found an error

```
adarshs-MacBook-Air:Desktop adarshak$ g++ hellow.cpp
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path 
(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

anyone plese help me to find out the error

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Comment: sorry for that but even i correncted that the error was same

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you don't have the command line developer tools installed. Run this command from Terminal once:

```
xcode-select --install
```

This will bring up the download & installation UI. Follow this through to the end. (It may take a while depending on the speed of your internet connection.)

From then on compiling should work.